# Throttling IPv6 requests - what would be a suitable subnet size?

Tags: web-application, ipv6

I'm trying to come up with a request throttling policy for a web application based on IP addresses.

For throttling requests for users on IPv4, a subnet size of /32 (i.e. a single IP address) is often good enough, since end users are very often allocated a single IP address.

However, IPv6 address allocations to end users are an entirely different story; since an user can receive multiple IP addresses; and they can easily switch IP addresses within the subnet allocated to them, so a policy of blocking with a /128 subnet (i.e. a single IP address) obviously is not going to work.

What would be a good policy (subnet size) on which user requests could be throttled for IPv6?

Comment: Customers will usually get a /48 (organisations) or a /56 (home users) => e.g. https://www.ripe.net/about-us/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing , although it seems there are occurrences users get a /64 (which is the absolute minimum).

Comment: The delegated prefix size, and even if prefixes are assigned dynamically, are still very different for each ISP. We're working on best practice documentation on that: https://ripe73.ripe.net/programme/meeting-plan/bcop-tf. If filtering on /128 is too loose for you then the next logical step is /64. Also note that the RIPE database documents the delegated prefix sizes if your users are from that region.

Comment: A RIR-agnostic document describing the same can be found on https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6177, which will lead to the same conclusion: end sites will get anything from a /48 to a /64. Of course, it might be possible that future directives will change (again ;) ).